# UITableView with different UITableViewCells and dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In our app we often use `UITableViews` to display different custom `UITableViewCells` in a scrollable list by using a list of display items with a type as the data source. In the `TableView`'s `cellforRowAt` function we then decide which custom `UITableViewCell` to use depending on the display item's type.

This approach is now causing a problem in a `UITableViewCell` that loads and displays an image from the internet as the view doesn't know the image's size yet.

This is the custom view I'm trying to build: [see custom UITableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCMV1.png)

However, I tried to start with just the image inside of my custom view. As the `TableView` row doesn't know how big the image is going to be, no image is displayed when the view appears. Only after scrolling down and up to the point where the image should be, the cell is getting resized as I want it to be. I set top, leading and trailing constraints of the image to 0 so the image fills the cell completely.

What is best practice for loading images and displaying them in such cells with the cell being resized depending on the actual image size?

in `viewDidLoad` I set

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
let cell: CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
cell.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
tableView.beginUpdates()
cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: item.getImageUrl()), placeholder: nil, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
cell.isUserInteractionEnalbed = false
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
cell.accessoryType = .none

return cell
```

Comment: are you loading images from network api..?

Comment: I use the library [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to load images from the internet into UIImageViews

Comment: its ok. can I know you where you are getting that image urls.

Comment: The particular image comes from our CMS and has no fixed size

Comment: Make sure you have set automaticDimension for the row height and that you have constraints from the top to the bottom of the cell. You must also return some value from `estimatedHeightForRow` and finally, when the image is loaded call `beginUpdates` followed by `endUpdates` to get the tableview to relayout the visible cells

Comment: get the image size from the backend and add that property to model. calculate the height according to size received from the backend. adjust height of cell in height for row at index path by getting the object from the datasource.

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen: No need to calculate height and width, in can easily be done by self sizing cells.

Comment: @ThomasGöhringer: Can you please show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you are setting the image.

Comment: @ThomasGöhringer if image is coming from internet then you need to fix the image otherwise your cells jump when reuse or image going out of bound. Or if you want to make imageview bigger means actual size of image then you need to know the image size before you load the image

Comment: @iPeter see edited question

Comment: Write `beginUpdates` before `kf.setImage` and `endUpdates` after setting the image, not within the closure.

Comment: Doesn't work either

Comment: It works perfectly if you do everything correctly, you're sure you are not setting height anywhere?

Comment: Can't find any place where I set a height except the expectedRowHeight. I don't know if this has something to do with it but when I leave `endUpdates` within the closure and put a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` with 0.1s the image is displayed. However, all other rows below the image are not displayed anymore.

Comment: @iPeter I added a click handler to call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` manually. When that handler gets triggered, the image is resized correctly. This leads me to think that somehow the callback of `setImage` is returned too early.

Comment: Is your image large or small? Smaller than 80 pixels may be? Please show the layout of the `tableViewCell` once if you can.

Comment: The image is bigger than 80 pixels. The layout is simple a `TableViewCell` containing a `UIView` with the `UIImageView`. The `UIImageView` has top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to the Superview set to 0. I hope this is enough for you as it might be difficult to show you because of corporate rules. If you need more settings just tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. The data I'm displaying is provided by a presenter and not there initially. That's why I'm calling `tableView.reloadData()` after I have it. The problem was that I didn't call that method explicitly in the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are configuring your tableview or when your view loads:
write these:

```
yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0 // this can be any height you want to set when table loads first time.
yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

or you can set these settings from storyboard/xib if you are configuring it from there.[image] see here settings for uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be reloading that particular row, if visible, after image downloading finishes.

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPathForRow], with: .none)
```

As you are saying that image is getting shown perfectly after scrolling down and up gain, I believe this solution should work.

Comment: Brought no change for me